# Fixing TypeError "range.getAs is not a function" with Apps Script's blob

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, blob

I wanted to export range A1:I13 of the current active sheet (only sheet) as PDF, then send via email, but encountered this error

range.getAs is not a function

```
function generateAndEmailPDF() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:I13");

  var pdfBlob = range.getAs('application/pdf').setName('timesheet.pdf').setPageOrientation(DocumentApp.Orientation.LANDSCAPE);

  var recipient = "thisismyemail12345678@gm63495.com";
  var subject = "PDF Test";
  var body = "Please find attached a PDF generated from the current sheet.";
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {attachments: [pdfBlob]});
}
```

I edited the sheet to only contain data in that specific range and re-attempted with sheet.getAs instead. Still not working. Cells A1:A2 are merged and contain a PNG image fitting inside the cell. Any pointers on how to fix this error?

---

Working script, using different method:

```
function saveAndSendReport() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var date = sheet.getRange("A7").getValue().toLocaleDateString("en-US", {day: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', year: '2-digit'}).replace(/\/|\\/g, "/");
  var documentName = "My Working Logs for " + date;
  var pdf = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName(documentName);

  // Set the PDF output to be landscape
  var pageOptions = {width: 11, height: 8, orientation: 'landscape'};
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Working Logs").next();
  var file = folder.createFile(pdf).setPageOptions(pageOptions);
  
  var message = {
    to: "thisismyemail12345@gmail.com",
    subject: "Working Logs, Week of " +date,
    body: "Hellow,\n\nPlease see attached for my Working Logs 
(ID# 12345) for the week starting "+date+ ".\n\nThank you,\nMe",
    name: "Me",
    attachments: [file]
  }
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

Comment: There is no method getAs() for [Range}(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).  Are you trying to create a PDF and attach it to an email or do you want to display the table in the email?

Comment: I'm trying to create a PDF from a range of the named sheet and attach it to an email. From reading the documentation and poking around on this site, getAs is a private function that I copied and pasted, senselessly. What should be my next step in debugging the blob error

Comment: Thank you; it works! I learned a new thing that you can use the EXPORT URL to send email with pointers in the link you shared. However I want to hard-code the email into the script itself, not having to pull from cell(s) in the spreadsheet so I use a different, shorter code block, copying from unknown origin!